# Run code from MainActivity in another Class

Tags: android, class, methods

Alright, so I made a class for my custom top menu bar because I thought that would be convinient. And now I have a slight problem. I want `MainActivity.class` to handle which views to display and whatnot. But the onClick listener is within the `TopMenu.class` what is the easiest way of activating the method within MainActivity from the other class? (If there is any)

MainActivity.class method:

```
public void setScene(String scene) {...}
```

TopMenu.class:

```
private void clickButton(String btnName) {
    if (active) {
        switch (btnName) {
            case "Run": {
                //Example of what I want...
                parentContext.setScene("test");
                break;
            }
            case "Shop": {
                break;
            }
            case "Play": {
                break;
            }
            case "List": {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a copy of the `Context` and the `View` from `MainActivity` already if that helps with the process...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to cast the context as your activity (since the `Context` class does not contain a method named `setScene`).

Something like this:

```
if(parentContext != null){
    ((MainActivity)parentContext).setScene("test");
}
```

Alternatively, you can create an interface:

```
public interface SceneControlInterface {
    public void setScene(String scene);
}
```

Then when you instantiate your TopMenu, you can pass an instance of your interface to it (of course you'd have to modify your constructor method to accept it):

```
TopMenu mMenu = new TopMenu(new SceneControlInterface(){
    @Override
    public void setScene(String scene){
        //do something with scene
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper class that holds your `setScene(...)` method. Use Singleton pattern or simply declare `setScene(...)` as a static method.

```
public class SceneHelper{
        public static void setScene(String scene, View viewToBeChanged){
            //Your stuff
        }
    }
```

That would be one way.